# Handling Java instant Ajax request/respond with Angular

Tags: java, javascript, angular.js, spring

I am trying to build a food search app. I am using Angular and Spring. I am currently using the yelp API, but it's done on the Java side.

I think what I have achieved is really bad design. It works, but the data is not always updated correctly.

For Java, I created two methods and one string variable:

```
private String response;

@RequestMapping(value = "/searchRestaurant", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public void searchRestaurantWithYelp(@RequestBody String jsonData) {

    //here i process the json string and pass the values to yelp function,
    // then yelp sends the respond as a json string, i assigned the value
    // to the response variable.
    response = queryYelp();
}
```

As you can see, this post request receive a json string from client side, and pass the string to the yelp java API I created. The yelp respond is a json string, and I assign it to the response variable.

I also created a GET method, which simply returns the response, which contains the data yelp returned. I want to immediately return this data to the client/browser, with angular.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "restaurantResult", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public String returnRestaurantSearchResultWithYelp() {
    return response;
}
```

Now for my JS/angular side of code:

```
function HomeCtrl($scope, $http) {
    $scope.term = "";
    $scope.location = "";
    $scope.submitSearch = function () {
        var data = {
            term: $scope.term,
            location: $scope.location
        }; //end data
        var res = $http.post('/searchRestaurant', data);
        $http.get('/restaurantResult').
              success(function (data) {
        $scope.response = data;
        });
    }
 }
```

I wrapped a `$http.get` inside the `$http.post`. This function first sends data, which invoke my Java post method, then retrieves the data right after. I am binding the json data with angular so my app is single page. And with angular two way data binding the `{{response}}` contains the yelp response and will display instantly to the user.

My simplified HTML:

```
 <input type="text" ng-model="term"/>
 <input type="text" ng-model="location"/>
 <button ng-click="submitSearch()">Search</button>

 {{response}}
```

It works, sort of. But I feel there is a better way to do it.

The issue: The `{{response}}` sometimes cannot be updated instantly. For instance, I search burger king, the response will show me the address, location, etc. Then I type McDonalds, the response still shows the info of Burger King. I have to refresh the browser to get the latest and correct response.

I was wondering what the issue is causing the response not update instantly? Is it because of browser cache?

In terms of the my project build design, what part I did wrong? Is there a better way to handle this type of request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I type McDonalds, the response still shows the info of Burger King. I have to refresh the browser to get the latest and correct response.

The request is being made before the previous post completes.

In your Angular, you need to **chain** your `$http` actions

```
function HomeCtrl($scope, $http) {
    $scope.term = "";
    $scope.location = "";
    $scope.submitSearch = function () {
        var data = {
            term: $scope.term,
            location: $scope.location
        }; //end data
        var res = $http.post('/searchRestaurant', data);

        //chain from the post
        res.then ( function() { 
            return $http.get('/restaurantResult').
        }).then ( function(result) {
            $scope.response = result.data;
            return data;
        }).catch ( function(error) {
            //log error
            throw error;
        });

        //return for further chaining
        return res;
    }
 }
```

By **chaining** your actions, you guarantee that the previous action completes before starting the next.

Notice that the `.then` method returns data differently than the `.success` method.

Also I avoid the `.success` and `.error` methods for two reasons: They **ignore return values** and they are **deprecated**. For more information on tbe deprecation of `.success` and `.error`, see the [AngularJS $http Service API Reference -- deprecation notice](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice).

For more information on chaining see [AngularJS $q Service API Reference - chaining promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#chaining-promises).

### UPDATE

To answer you questions about the differences between `.then` and `.catch` methods and the deprecated `.success` and `.error` methods.

The `$http` service `.then` method returns a **response object** to its resolve callback.

```
// Simple GET request example:
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/someUrl'
}).then(function resolveCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }, function catchCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

The response object has these properties:

- data – {string|Object} – The response body transformed with the transform functions.
- status – {number} – HTTP status code of the response.
- headers – {function([headerName])} – Header getter function.
- config – {Object} – The configuration object that was used to generate the request.
- statusText – {string} – HTTP status text of the response.

--- [AngularJS $http Service API Reference -- general usage](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#general-usage)

> Deprecated: The `$http` service `.success` method spreads out the response object.

```
// Simple GET request example :
$http.get('/someUrl').
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }).
  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

As I said before, **avoid** these method for two reasons: they **ignore return values** and they are **deprecated**.

The rule of thumb for functional programming is **always return something**. By ignoring return values, `.success` and `.error` break that rule. What makes promises powerful is **returning** and **chaining**.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Good job on your first answer.

Comment: How exactly `.then` returns different data than `.success`?

Comment: @JasonZ see updated answer.

Comment: @georgeawg great. thanks for the detailed answer.